# Maven war has META-INF folder in two places

Tags: maven, package, war, meta-inf

I'm working on a project which uses JAAS and unfortunately for me Tomcat requires a file to be put in a META-INF folder in the root of the war

```
app.war
  |__META-INF
  |    |___context.xml
 ...
```

I think that it's already weird since the default META-INF location for WAR's is in the classes folders.

```
app.war
  |__WEB-INF
  |    |__classes
  |         |__META-INF
 ...
```

So I'm using Maven, which states that anything in src/main/resources/META-INF will be copied to the appropriate place, which it does. The weird thing is that it is also creating a META-INF folder in the root of the file structure leaving me with 2 META-INF folders.

**Project Structure**

```
app
  |__src/main/java
  |__src/main/resources
  |       |__META-INF
  |             |__context.xml
 ...
```

**After mvn package**

```
 app
  |__META-INF [1]
  |__WEB-INF
  |     |__classes
  |           |__META-INF [2]
  |                  |__context.xml
 ...
```

So, if the war standard states that META-INF should be under classes folder, as in #2, why maven war creates the #1 folder. And is there a way to make it copy files into that folder instead of #2?

Regards

Answer (score 14):

So I found this:

[Two Meta-Inf folders - normal structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238615/two-meta-inf-folders-normal-structure?rq=1)

which states that having 2 META-INF folders is not a problem. Digging a little I found:

[JAR File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html)

which states about the META-INF folder:

> A  JAR file is essentially a zip file that contains an optional META-INF directory. ...The META-INF directory, if it exists, is used to store package and extension configuration data, including security, versioning, extension and services.

and this:

[JSR-000315 JavaTM Servlet 3.0](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/)

which, on section 10.6, states about the WAR file structure:

> When packaged into such a form, a META-INF directory will be present which
>   contains information useful to Java archive tools. **This directory must not be directly
>   served as content by the container in response to a Web client’s request, though its
>   contents are visible to servlet code via the getResource and getResourceAsStream
>   calls on the ServletContext.** Also, any requests to access the resources in META-INF
>   directory must be returned with a SC_NOT_FOUND(404) response.

So from the WAR spec the right place is WEB-INF/classes/META-INF. Yet, since war is a special jar file, it makes sense to have /META-INF as a point for extensions. One can see such different uses in JPA persistence.xml vs. Tomcat context.xml files: the former should be placed in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF while the latter in /META-INF.

Comment: A .war file is a .jar file, so it can have META-INF directory just like .jar file.

Comment: @Hong A .war file is a .zip file, just like a .jar file.  You can add more files to it so the same file can function as both a .war and a .jar file.  This is how Jenkins is distributed https://www.jenkins.io/download/