# What is the correct META-INF directory location for context.xml in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, context.xml, meta-inf

Should a "context.xml" file for deploying application-specific configuration to Tomcat be placed in:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/context.xml
```

...or...

```
src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml ?
```

*Justification for asking: Have seen conflicting advice on StackOverflow and could not find the specific location mentioned in the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).*

Comment: I think WebContent/META-INF/context.xml is the right place

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The documentation is indeed not specific about this.

It is `src/main/webapp/META-INF` since the file needs to end up deployed in the web root/META-INF folder, not in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link to back this up? Interestingly, persistence.xml *should* be deployed there according to [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnbrj/index.html): "If you package the persistence unit as a set of classes in a WAR file, persistence.xml should be located in the WAR file’s WEB-INF/classes/META-INF directory." If what you said is true, I guess this would imply a need for more than one META-INF location.

Comment: Nothing interesting about it. persistence.xml is something entirely different and needs to be on the classpath (you can also use it in standard client applications). No I don't have a link to back it up since the official documentation doesn't explicitly state it. You can try it out yourself right now to confirm it.

Comment: OK, maybe "interesting" was the wrong word :-) But I'd assumed there would be only one `META-INF` folder in a web application - seems this was wrong.

Comment: Ah, just found a similar question and someone who backs up what you said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997731/maven-war-has-meta-inf-folder-in-two-places#18017123) - answer accepted.